# Losing mocking if the mocked object sets to null in the implementation class

Tags: java, mockito

I want to mock an Object which works in a loop. Code to be tested in such a way that the object (which I want to mock) gets re initializes at every iteration. So when I am mocking I can see Mocked object is there at first time but losing after re intialization.

```
loop {
TripPlan tripPlan = solver.make(something);
        solver= new ArkSolver();
}
```

solver is the object I want to mock.

Test code:

```
public class TestArkTripPlanManager { 
   @Mock Solver solver; 
   PlanManager planManager; 
   @Test 
   public void testExecute_Two_Ark() throws RoutingServiceException, IOException, VRPSolverException {
      when(solver.make(case1).thenReturn(expectedcase1); 
      when(solver.make(case2).thenReturn(expectedcase2); 
      planManager.setsolver(solver);
      planManager.execute(); 
   }
```

Comment: Can you please add your test code?

Comment: Find below Pseudo code  ``` public class TestArkTripPlanManager {
    @Mock
    Solver solver;

    PlanManager planManager;
    @Test
    public void testExecute_Two_Ark() throws RoutingServiceException, IOException, VRPSolverException {
        when(solver.make(case1).thenReturn(expectedcase1);
        when(solver.make(case2).thenReturn(expectedcase2);
        planManager.setsolver(solver);
        planManager.execute();
    }

Comment: In future, please add any code related to the question in the question itself by editing it and not in the comments. I've done it for you now.

Comment: Renjith did Rashin's answer help you? Are you able to run your test fine now?

Comment: @MadhuBhat That was not required. I modified the code to not re initialize ArkSolver.

Comment: So is your problem solved?

Comment: yes problem Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change how you acquire the solver.

```java
solver = acquireSolver();

ArkSolver acquireSolver() {
    return new ArkSolver();
}
```

Then from the test you can control what kind of solver you provide from this method.

```java
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    underTest = new MyClass() {
        @Override
        public ArkSolver acquireSolver() {
            return <your mock here>;
        }
    };
}
```

I don't know why you want to create a new solver every time (maybe some internal states remains after the `make` method) but you can try to reset the solver to its initial state so you can re-use it again.